# Why this question might be deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

A post of mine was well upvoted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032996/clang-wont-compile-a-simple-c-program-including-math-h-but-gcc-will/19033027#19033027

I also still have the reputation of that post.

But when I try to go to that link there comes:

> Page Not Found
>
> This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the help center for possible explanations why a question might be removed.

I can't imgaine that is a local problem for me.

And the Question was absolutly on topic for stack overflow.

So is it a (local) bug and there is nothing deleted?
And if not so:
is there a way to look up WHY it got deleted? because if it go delted, I'm sure, this happened
by misstake.

Comment: It was marked as a duplicate with 3 downvotes (and 4 upvotes) and 3 people voted to delete it.

Comment: strange. With what reason?

Comment: beeing a duplicate is reason for deletetion? As in my eyes tis post was better to find and also beter to understand for others who will cross that problem.

Comment: Not sure entirely why it was deleted, or the timing. But as @Sotirios notes, it was deleted by three regular (high-rep) users.

Comment: @AndrewBarber is there any way to veto that decission?

Comment: Why change it?  You failed to link a required lib & so the linker could not resolve an external.  I dread to think of how many dups of that exist.

Comment: @MartinJames: the point is: it is not "A" required lib. It is >the< math lib. which is a special case on how to link and differs from all other cases. I had the same problem as the asker before, and had like 5 days full time of my work to look up whats the error in a big project, which had to be build on powerPC arch. So additional there was a bug in clang, which throw a wrong error and also some times clang core dumped. And there was nothing to find on SO what told me that -lm has to be the last linker flag. Well, "undefined reference to `log'" Would have helped. ...

Comment: ... But by that post's title, thats something I wouldn't look for, when I'm sure I have linked math lib. But the deleted post, would had helped me out, by figguring out that THIS SPECIAL CASE has to be the last argument. So marking it as duplicate is ok... But deleting it, is a loss of knowledge and absolutly over the top in my view.

Comment: @MartinJames ... And some questions have [far too many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/218384?lq=1) dups. Cleaning up excess duplicate questions can indeed be a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

The question was unilaterally marked as a duplicate of [undefined reference to `log'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145264/undefined-reference-to-log) by a gold-badge holder, and was subsequently deleted by votes from three community members.

Comment: We don't normally delete duplicates because they can be used to signpost users coming in from google to the right question (by having different wording)
 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates